# PIC SPI Master and Slave at same time

Tags: pic, spi, mplabx

I need to implement an SPI slave device, and SPI master, the idea is an SPI "middle man".

I'm familiar with AVR and mbed development, but I lost contact with PICs a long time ago so this will be an opportunity to reconnect.

## Requirements:

1. DIP package
2. 2048-3000 bytes RAM to hold variable data
3. 2 x SPI channels one for master and other for the slave
4. MPLAB XC* Free version
5. 3.3 V logic & VCC

I went to MAPS and I got a few options, and I picked the PIC18F27K40.

## Questions:

1. Is possible to handle master and slave SPI channels at same time?
2. Can I rely only on the internal clock ? I'm worried about the performance (slave SPI)
3. Should I pick a different PIC?
4. Any sample code/snippet or link, I'm worried how to handle (forward) data to the second SPI line while being available to the master.

Comment: When you say master and slave, is that a single channel that is working as a master and slave, or two channels one working as a master and the other as a slave?

Comment: two channels one working as a master and the other as a slave

Comment: SPI is a synchronous protocol, you shouldn't need to worry about the accuracy of the clock.  Whether the clock will be fast enough depends on the data rates and the amount of processing that will be required from the PIC.  You haven't written anything about that.

Comment: the master clock is 2000000

Comment: The chip you picked has two SPI peripherals, and that's the easy way to meet the hardware timing specs for both channels, but it's really not that hard at all to bit-bang a correct SPI master.  (slave is slightly harder because you don't have as much control)  Just write a (probably high-priority interrupt-driven) software driver to handle the bit timing, and then the rest of your code can treat it like another peripheral.  I've done that when I only needed one SPI bus but had to use those specific pins for something else.  Bit-banged master to peripheral slave: worked just fine...

Comment: ...You can use a cheaper chip this way, by only requiring one SPI peripheral instead of two.

Answer (score 0):

The SPI channels themselves are fast enough, and they can be interrupt driven which gives you that option. Two factors that are most likely to impact your methodology are:

1) How many other tasks will the PIC need to perform beyond managing the two SPI ports? If you are performing continuous CPU intensive processing and also trying to keep both SPI ports fully occupied then you might find it difficult. As a practical matter I don't suspect there would be a problem, but I don't know the details of your application.

2) How are the other slave and master devices going to be synchronized with this PIC? Will there be handshaking required?. If the slaves cannot guarantee the availability of data at all times when the masters might begin a transfer then some type of synchronization/handshaking is required. I usually plan on using at least one additional I/O line as a handshake line per SPI channel.

- It might be useful to know that you can vary the SPI data line connections to suit your needs. For example, you could have the other master read a byte directly from the other slave, while also leaving a copy of the byte in your PIC SPI slave input buffer. Or, your PIC SPI master could read a byte from the other slave SPI while also sending a copy of the byte to a third slave. What makes this possible is that the data send and receive registers are basically just shift registers.